# Ordered List within Div on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, html, html-lists

I am trying to add styles on div on each LI. However, it is causing the number to stay as '1' only on IE.

`<ol>`

`<div><li>a</li></div>`

`<div><li>b</li></div>`

`</ol>`

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: div element cannot be nested in an <ol> tag.. <li> tags should be directly under <ol> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not valid html at all, so there is no way to know what that will end up looking like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ol>
    <li><span>a</span></li>
    <li><span>b</span></li>
</ol>
```

BTW, for the simplest case, you don't need the divs inside the list items.

Edit: changed `<div>` to `<span>` as no block elements are valid inside list-items.

Comment: Please don't do that. div in li is not valid html. Use span instead of div.